# Setting up wildfly to start on reboot in ubuntu 16

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly-8, wildfly-10, wildfly-9

Setting up wildfly to start on reboot in ubuntu 16 by executing:

```
sudo update-rc.d /etc/init.d/wildfly defaults
```

gives the following error:

```
update-rc.d: error: initscript does not exist: /etc/init.d//etc/init.d/wildfly
```

what could be the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
sudo update-rc.d wildfly defaults
```